# How Android EditText inputType attribute with value textMultiLine breaks the lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have an `EditText` field with the attribute inputType set to textMultiLine, this breaks a text into several lines, so far so good. I attached a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` so I can check for any change. In the method afterTextChanged I want to check when a line of text is broken into 2 lines, but the textMultiLine attribute does not add a new line char, so my question is:

How can I check how many lines of text have been written in an `EditText` with the inputType attribute set to textMultiLine if there is not new line character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a `Runnable` or post to a message queue. Simply call `EditText.getLineCount()` in your `afterTextChanged()` method:

```
final EditText editText = /* your EditText here */;
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        int numLines = editText.getLineCount();
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Line count: " + editText.getLineCount());
    }
});
```

`getLineCount()` will be called on UI thread when `editText` rendering is completed.